# REST API - Attach a file to an AP Credit Adjustment via key fields

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to attach a file to a Credit Adjustment via REST API by indicating the key fields.

For a regular Bill, this PUT request is successful:

```
https://{URL}/entity/Default/18.200.001/Bill/Bill/003838/files/Attachment Test 2.pdf
```

However, I am having issues identifying how should the **Key1** be changed for Credit Adjustments.
I have tried a series of combinations w/o success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
http://localhost/YourERP/entity/Default/20.200.001/Bill/ACR/[RefNbrHere]/files/EL Paso Texas.txt
```

Be sure that your file is included in the payload

[image]

Comment: that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know Chris already answered but I wanted to share that you can find these values for any other drop down key field by opening a record of the doc type you want and looking at the URL

[image]

Comment: Great input. Thanks @kyle!